# Spring Boot 3.0.0 compatibility with keycloak-spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm getting an error after adding keycloak-spring-boot-starter and removing Spring security which I had originally. I switched because I thought the configuration was simpler and more opinionated.

To be honest, I don't know what the difference between 3.0.0-M1 and 2.6.3 is. I'm trying to learn Spring Boot by creating a simple RESTful HTTP API that is protected by keycloak.

Is v3 recommended or should 2.6.3 be used? I'm finding it very hard to find appropriate, complete information in the Java world.

Startup log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v3.0.0-M1)

2022-02-21 12:58:14.469  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] de.icod.recipe.RecipeApplication         : Starting RecipeApplication using Java 17.0.2 on dev.luketic with PID 10181 (/home/darko/IdeaProjects/recipe/target/classes started by darko in /home/darko/IdeaProjects/recipe)
2022-02-21 12:58:14.471  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] de.icod.recipe.RecipeApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-21 12:58:14.507  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-02-21 12:58:14.508  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-02-21 12:58:14.895  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-21 12:58:14.916  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-21 12:58:15.417  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 3000 (http)
2022-02-21 12:58:15.421  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-21 12:58:15.421  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.16]
2022-02-21 12:58:15.464  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-21 12:58:15.465  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 956 ms
2022-02-21 12:58:15.491 ERROR 10181 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:719) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:401) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1279) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at de.icod.recipe.RecipeApplication.main(RecipeApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.ServletContext org.apache.catalina.Context.getServletContext()'
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.keycloakInit(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:111) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-17.0.0.jar:17.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.lifecycleEvent(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:70) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-17.0.0.jar:17.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

2022-02-21 12:58:15.492 ERROR 10181 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M2.jar:6.0.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:719) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:401) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1279) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
    at de.icod.recipe.RecipeApplication.main(RecipeApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0-M1.jar:3.0.0-M1]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.ServletContext org.apache.catalina.Context.getServletContext()'
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.keycloakInit(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:111) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-17.0.0.jar:17.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.lifecycleEvent(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:70) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-17.0.0.jar:17.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar:10.0.16]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

2022-02-21 12:58:15.493  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-02-21 12:58:15.499  WARN 10181 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-02-21 12:58:15.505  INFO 10181 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-21 12:58:15.515 ERROR 10181 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.keycloakInit(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:111)

The following method did not exist:

    'javax.servlet.ServletContext org.apache.catalina.Context.getServletContext()'

The calling method's class, org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/home/darko/.m2/repository/org/keycloak/spring-boot-container-bundle/17.0.0/spring-boot-container-bundle-17.0.0.jar!/org/keycloak/adapters/tomcat/AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.class

The called method's class, org.apache.catalina.Context, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/darko/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.0.16/tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar!/org/apache/catalina/Context.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.apache.catalina.Context: file:/home/darko/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.0.16/tomcat-embed-core-10.0.16.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve and org.apache.catalina.Context


Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### File *pom.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.icod</groupId>
    <artifactId>recipe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>recipe</name>
    <description>recipe</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>17.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: 3.0.0 is a milestone release and far from produyction ready. I highly doubt there already is a keycloack version available for that. Judging from the error it isn't as Spring Boot 3 is for JakartaEE and not JavaEE, the error indicates it requires JavaEE. So in short don't upgrade (as it isn't actually an upgrade nor should you be using Milestone versions in production).

Comment: I understand, tyvm. I'll try a new project with 2.6.3 and see if the error persists.

Comment: @Darko did you get this working on Spring Boot 3.0.x given that its stable now

Comment: I haven't touched spring boot again so far, at least not in connection with security and keycloak, sorry